# How to Compare Unicode Pandas dataframe column values to string value

Tags: pandas, python-unicode

I am looking at data from stats.nba.com/teams/gamelogs and get a dataframe for a particular game (http://stats.nba.com/game/#!/0021600836/). How do I select only the rows with column 'TEAM_CITY'=='Boston'?

```
df_total['TEAM_CITY'].values
```

gives an ouput:

```
array([u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston',
   u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston', u'Boston',
   u'Boston', u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago',
   u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago',
   u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago', u'Chicago'], dtype=object)
```

I do pip install of nba_py, and my code is the following:

```
from nba_py import game, team
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Constants
game_id = ['0021600849','0021600836']
tID = '1610612738'

bs = game.Boxscore(game_id=game_id[0], season='2016-17', season_type='Regular Season', range_type='0', start_period='0', end_period='0', start_range='0', end_range='0')
df_total = bs.player_stats()

df_total['TEAM_CITY'].values
df_total['TEAM_CITY'] = df_total['TEAM_CITY'=='Boston']
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `df_total[df_total['TEAM_CITY']=='Boston']`?

Comment: Ohh! I didn't realize it had to have the scope of the whole dataframe. I think df_total = df_total[df_total['TEAM_CITY'=='Boston']] works.

Comment: This works: df_total = df_total[df_total['TEAM_CITY']=='Boston'.encode('utf-8')]